# How to write FactoryGirl for has_one association with autosave: true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

The question is a little bit long. Please bear with me for a moment. Here are model `order` and `order item`. A `order` has_one `order item`.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order_item, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy, validate: true
  validates_associated :order_item
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  #validations
end
```

Since there is no nested attributes declared for `order_item`, there is no `order_item`'s attributes declared in `order` controllers for `mass assignment`.

Simplified `order` view

```
<%=simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%=f.input :order_date %>
  <%=render :inline 'order_item', locals: {f: f} %>
<% end %>
```

partial view `_order_items.html.erb`

```
<%=simple_fields_for :order_item do |f| %>
  <%=f.input :prod_name %>
<% end %>
```

My question is that how to represent `order` with FactoryGril for the `order` view above.

```
  order_item = FactoryGirl.build(:order_item)
  order = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order, order_item: order_item(??))
```

Does `order_item_attribues: order_item` seems not working (it is not a surprise because there is no nested attributes declared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass the `order_item` object directly into the `attributes_for`:

```
order_item = FactoryGirl.build(:order_item)
order = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order, order_item: order_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have something like in tests:

```
order_item_attrs = FactoryGirl.build(:order_item)
order_attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order, order_item_attributes: order_item_attrs)
```

But to accept nested attributes to the order initialize method as should add:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   accept_nested_attributes_for :order_item
end
```

Comment: Can not declare `accept_nested_attributes_for :order_item` in `order`.